# Apply sed line by line

Tags: sed

Does any one know how to apply sed line by line and not directly on a file text :

```
for i in $(cat server); do
    Exclude_List="AF|PO" 
    echo $i | egrep $LBB3B
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    **do my sed on the $i line only then continue on next line**
    fi
done
```

Comment: Have no idea what exactly are you looking with that, but you can pass that line to `sed` with _here-string_ `sed .... <<<"$i"` as well as piping to it `echo "$i" | sed ....  `.

Comment: I edited your question to format the code section. You do that by indenting all lines of code four spaces. As for your question, before you decide you need to use `sed` for something, you need to figure out whether it's the correct tool for the job. `sed` is a ***stream*** *editor*, that's **s**tream **ed**itor. It's not designed for doing what you want. Don't get me wrong; you could wire something up Rube Goldberg style, but don't. Just pick the correct tool for the job. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` already works line by line:

```
sed -E '/AF|PO/{ ...sed expression to apply when matching... }' server
```

For example, only print the lines matching that regular expression:

```
sed -nE '/AF|PO/p' server
```

The `-E` flag to `sed` makes the utility interpret the regular expression as an extended regular expression, and the `-n` turns off the implicit outputting of every input line.

For doing multiple things to lines matching the expression, enclose these in `{ ... }`.  For example, print each matching line twice (and don't print non-matching lines):

```
sed -nE '/AF|OP/{p;p;}' server
```

Answer (score 1):

sed has line addressing capabilities, if that helps you:

```
$ seq 5 > input
$ sed '3s/.*/jeff/' input
1
2
jeff
4
5
$ sed '3,5s/.*/new/' input
1
2
new
new
new
```

Instead of [using a shell loop to process a text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/117549), consider a tool that more naturally processes text, such as [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ cat input
AF bar
PO baz
other stuff
more other stuff


$ awk '/(AF)|PO/ { print }' input
AF bar
PO baz

$ awk '/stuff/ && !/more/ { print }' input
other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not what `sed` is for. You can use the native abilities of the shell do everything "line-by-line".

Comment: Um, what is `sed` used for then, according to you?